# Creative X-Fi Titanium Started to Freeze Operating System

Tags: freeze

Firstly my computer specs are :

- **Mainboard :** Asus P8z68-V  (Latest Bios)
- **Cpu :** İ7 2600k @ 4.7Ghz
- **Ram :** 16gb Kingston 2200Mhz ~1.6V
- **Gpu :** 2x Asus 7970 @ stock
- **Ssd :** Kingston 128 GB
- **HDD :** 2tb Western Digital Caviar Black 7200 Rpm
- **Monitor :** Samsung 27" S27a950d @1920x1080 120hz
- **Soundcard :** Creative X-fi Titanium
- **Operating System :** Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64 Bit
- **Optical Drive :** Asus

**and all drivers are up-to-date.**

**Problem indicators:**

**1)** 3 days ago **my computer freezed while i was playing a game**.(Screen freezed,couldn't move Mouse and couldn't type anything with keyboard and **extremely disturbing sound came from the headphone which is connected to the Creative X-fi Titanium soundcard**) I pressed the reset button and restarted my computer. After this freeze, Windows couldn't boot and showed a blue screen. I turned off computer and waited some time and successfully booted to Windows.

**2)**  **While watching online streaming videos**, **video randomly stops for 1 second and continues.(No problem with sound, only video stops and countinue**). No problem with playing movies from HDD.

**3)**  **My computer completely freezes very rarely while watching online streaming videos** and extremely disturbing sound came from the headphone which is connected to the Creative X-fi Titanium soundcard).

**4)** Sometimes computer **shows blue screen of death**, **if i try to enable or disable Creative X-Fi Titanium sound card from device manager**.

**What i tried until now:**

- **Tested rams** with memtest. **No problem at all**.
- **Tested my gpus and psu** with Furmark(under highest stress). **No problem at all**.
- **Checked temperatures** of every hardware while under stress testing. **No problem at all**.
- **Checked my HDD and SSd** with Hd Tune Pro for r/w errors and bad sectors. **No problem at all**.
- **Checked my Cpu with Prime95** and after some time **computer freezed** and again extremely disturbing  sound came from the headphone which is connected to the Creative X-fi Titanium soundcard. After this i downclocked my cpu and tried again but computer freezed again after some time.

**The most importantly** ,**I tried to disable Creative X-Fi Titanium soundcard from device manager and all problems solved**. **No more random freezing while playing games,no problem with streaming videos, no more freezing while playing streaming videos, no more freezing while stressing my cpu with**  **prime95** .

**My questions are :**

**1)** If this is a hardware problem about my soundcard, is there anything i can do about this soundcard? Can i repair it ?

**2)** Is a failing soundcard can couse my cpu fail at prime95 test ?

**3)** I'm using unofficial(Not released to public, just spread accidentally by Microsoft) Windows 8.1 Update 1. Is this update can couse this problem ?

Please help me, and my apologies if my English is bad..
Thanks...

Comment: İ saw it from here http://www.tomshardware.com/news/windows-8.1-update-1-microsoft-download-metro,26240.html . And installed it as 6 Windows update files 1.KB2919442
2.KB2939087
3.KB2932046
4.KB2919355
5.KB2938439
6.KB2937592 and i already scanned my system for virusses, couldn't find anything.

Comment: Sounds like the hardware is to blame. If you suspect the unreleased update is to blame roll back your system and yes that could be the cause!